# Reporting a thread progress to main thread in C++

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

In C/C++ How can I make the threads(POSIX pthreads/Windows threads) to give me a safe method to pass progress back to the main thread on the progress of the execution or my work that I’ve decided to perform with the thread.

Is it possible to report the progress in terms of percentage ?

Comment: Which OS? What type of app? If it's a gui windows app, just use PostMessage.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to assume a very simple case of a main thread, and one function.  What I'd recommend is passing in a pointer to an atomic (as suggested by Kirill above) for each time you launch the thread.  Assuming C++11 here.

```
using namespace std;

void threadedFunction(atomic<int>* progress)
{
    const chrono::milliseconds dura( 2000 );
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        progress->store(i);  // updates the variable safely
        this_thread::sleep_for(dura); // Sleeps for a bit
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Make and launch 10 threads
    const size_t NUM_THREADS = 10;
    vector<atomic<int>> atomics(NUM_THREADS, 0);
    vector<thread> threads;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        threads.emplace_back(threadedFunction, &atomics[i]);
    }

    // Monitor the threads down here
    // use atomics[n].load() to get the value from the atomics
    return 0;
}
```

I think that'll do what you want.  I omitted polling the threads, but you get the idea.  I'm passing in an object that both the main thread and the child thread know about (in this case the `atomic<int>` variable) that they both can update and/or poll for results.  If you're not on a full C++11 thread/atomic support compiler, use whatever your platform determines, but there's always a way to pass a variable (at the least a `void*`) into the thread function.  And that's how you get something to pass information back and forth via non-statics.

Comment: It should be pointed out that a pointer to a vector element is not safe. That fact that you are resizing `atomics` may invalidate the pointers passed to the thread.

Comment: You're right.  You have to reserve all the space first or else those pointers could be invalidated.  Good catch.  A LinkedList<> would be a better choice here, as expanding it doesn't invalidate the existing elements.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to solve this is to use C++ atomics for that. Declare in some visible enough place:

```
std::atomic<int> my_thread_progress(0);
```

In a simple case this should be a static variable, in a more complex place this should be a data field of some object that manages threads or something similar.

On many platforms this will be slightly paranoiac because almost everywhere the read and write operations on integers are atomic. Bit using atomics still it makes because:

1. You will have guarantee that this will work fine on any platform, even on a 16 bit CPU or whatever unusual hardware;
2. Your code will be easier to read. Reader will immediately see that this is shared variable without placing any comments. Once it will be updated with `load`/`store` methods, it will be easier to catch on what is going on.

**EDIT**

Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual
Combined Volumes: 1, 2A, 2B, 2C, 3A, 3B and 3C (http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325462.pdf)

Volume 3A: 8.1.1 Guaranteed Atomic Operations

The Intel486 processor (and newer processors since) guarantees that the following basic memory operations will always be carried out atomically:

- Reading or writing a byte
- Reading or writing a word aligned on a 16-bit boundary
- Reading or writing a doubleword aligned on a 32-bit boundary

Comment: Hi Kirill, I need a mechanism to send information from a thread say Thread A to the main thread through messaging passing systems

Comment: If this is simple status data, declare several atomic vars. Otherwise use STL queue and protect access to this queue with STL mutex.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the very good answer by [@Kevin Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83839/kevin-anderson). It helped me doing this, here is a full version of code and few remarks :

1. `std::vector` cannot be used with `std::atomic`, it didn't compile with g++ for me, so I used `std::deque` instead.
2. the part using `load` (Actually, I am not using `load` or `store` because it is implicit when using `std::atomic`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>

void do_work(int size, std::atomic<int> &progress)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; ++i)
    {
        std::chrono::milliseconds dura(350);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura); // Sleeps for a bit
        progress = (100 * i) / size;
    }
}

void monitor_progress(std::deque<std::atomic<int>> &v_progress)
{
    bool isOver = false;
    while (not isOver)
    {
        isOver = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < v_progress.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << "T#" << i << ":" << v_progress[i] << "% ";
            if (v_progress[i] != 100)
            {
                isOver = false;
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::chrono::milliseconds dura(200);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura); // Sleeps for a bit
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int THREAD_NUMBER = 4;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads(THREAD_NUMBER);
    std::deque<std::atomic<int>> v_progress;
    // Make and launch THREAD_NUMBER threads
    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_NUMBER; ++i)
    {
        v_progress.emplace_back(0);
        threads[i] = std::thread(do_work, 10 * (i + 1), std::ref(v_progress[i]));
    }
    // Monitor the threads
    monitor_progress(std::ref(v_progress));

    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_NUMBER; ++i)
    {
        threads[i].join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output is looking like that and keeps until every thread ends

```
> .\atomic_progress_vector.exe
T#0:0% T#1:0% T#2:0% T#3:0%
T#0:0% T#1:0% T#2:0% T#3:0%
T#0:10% T#1:5% T#2:3% T#3:2%
T#0:10% T#1:5% T#2:3% T#3:2%
T#0:20% T#1:10% T#2:6% T#3:5%
T#0:20% T#1:10% T#2:6% T#3:5%
T#0:30% T#1:15% T#2:10% T#3:7%
T#0:40% T#1:20% T#2:13% T#3:10%
T#0:40% T#1:20% T#2:13% T#3:10%
```